# How to show caption in Nivo Slider only after hover event?

Tags: html, css, nivo-slider

I need to show caption of image in Nivo Slider after hover event.

I try to hide caption using css:

```
.nivo-caption {
    text-align: center;
    dislay:none;
}
```

And display this like as:

```
$('#slider').hover(function(){ $(".nivo-caption").show();});
```

But it does not work

Comment: Please create a Fiddle of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
$('#slider').mouseover(function(){ $("#slider").addClass("nivo-caption");});
```